# Azure Mobile Service HTML 5 user auth shows Windows Security dialogue box in IE (.NET backend)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am creating a HTML 5 app that uses a .net Azure Mobile Service and coming across a weird issue when trying to login a user on Internet Explorer (and only IE): It brings up a Windows Security dialogue box with the message :

> "The service (back-end url) is asking for your username and password.
>   The service reports that it is from Service"

Dismissing the dialogue box gives the error "Access is denied."

I've tried entering my application key for the password (as you would do when testing the api) but that did not work. I've set up CORS correctly as I can make calls that only require the application key and turned off intranet discovery. I even tried deploying to a azure website to see if was a local issue. No luck.

Chrome & firefox do not show the dialogue and does the callback as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and used Fiddler to inspect the differences between IE and Chrome. Chrome was not presenting this credential pop-up for Azure Mobile Service credentials and IE was. It turns out it is a `CORS` (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue in IE. If you inspect Fiddler, IE will report a `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` response for a cross domain GET call to AMS.

The solution is to go into the Azure Portal to your Azure Mobile Service and go into the 'Configure' tab. Within here you can set up and add the valid `CORS` URLs. This *does* include any addresses that are valid to call your service. It could be public and might be `*`. If you have it restricted make sure you include any 'localhost' addresses as well that might call the service during local development using IE.

For more information please see the following:
[Cross-origin resource sharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn155871.aspx/)